# Error when building PhoneGap app for BlackBerry (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, cordova, blackberry-10, phonegap-build, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to build a mobile app based on PhoneGap for blackberry and getting the following error:

```
    Running command: d:\app\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\build.bat
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[INFO]    Generating output files
[INFO]    java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]          at com.qnx.bbt.packager.Asset.setSourcePath(Asset.java:89)      at com.qnx.bbt.packager.Asset.<init>(Ass
et.java:76)     at com.qnx.bbt.xml.BbtExtensionXml.getAsset(BbtExtensionXml.java:583)   at com.qnx.bbt.xml.BbtExtensionX
ml.getAssets(BbtExtensionXml.java:553)  at com.qnx.bbt.packager.BbtBarValueProvider.getAssets(BbtBarValueProvider.java:2
02)     at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.getAssets(BARPackager.java:71)   at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.findAsset(BARPack
ager.java:257)  at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.associateSourceAssets(BARPackager.java:251)      at com.qnx.bbt.packager.
AbstractPackager.parseDescriptorAndCreateBarManifest(AbstractPackager.java:582) at com.qnx.bbt.packager.AbstractPackager
.doRun(AbstractPackager.java:243)       at com.qnx.bbt.packager.AbstractPackager.runPackager(AbstractPackager.java:169)
at com.qnx.bbt.nativepackager.BarNativePackager.main(BarNativePackager.java:64)
[INFO]    Error: null
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
[INFO]    java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]          at com.qnx.bbt.packager.Asset.setSourcePath(Asset.java:89)      at com.qnx.bbt.packager.Asset.<init>(Ass
et.java:76)     at com.qnx.bbt.xml.BbtExtensionXml.getAsset(BbtExtensionXml.java:583)   at com.qnx.bbt.xml.BbtExtensionX
ml.getAssets(BbtExtensionXml.java:553)  at com.qnx.bbt.packager.BbtBarValueProvider.getAssets(BbtBarValueProvider.java:2
02)     at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.getAssets(BARPackager.java:71)   at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.findAsset(BARPack
ager.java:257)  at com.qnx.bbt.bar.BARPackager.associateSourceAssets(BARPackager.java:251)      at com.qnx.bbt.packager.
AbstractPackager.parseDescriptorAndCreateBarManifest(AbstractPackager.java:582) at com.qnx.bbt.packager.AbstractPackager
.doRun(AbstractPackager.java:243)       at com.qnx.bbt.packager.AbstractPackager.runPackager(AbstractPackager.java:169)
at com.qnx.bbt.nativepackager.BarNativePackager.main(BarNativePackager.java:64)
[INFO]    Error: null
[ERROR]   Native Packager exception occurred
An error has occurred
Error: d:\app\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\build.bat: Command fai
led with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user123\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib
\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

The app builds just fine for Android, but it's not working for Blackberry.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any reserved file or folder names in your project.

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/creating_an_archive_file_1873325_11.html

Specifically, if your project has a folder under the root named "bin" or "src" you'll get this error.

Comment: Please copy this error instead of just leaving a link only answer as you have now.

Comment: I don't understand. The error message is in the original question. There's no reason to restate it.

My answer explains why he's getting the error (reserved file or folder name), I provide a link to a page which explains BlackBerry's naming rules and I explain what his specific problem is.

Comment: It's a Stackoverflow convention that we'll usually try to copy paste the relevant part of the answer from the page into your answer. This is done to avoid problems where the linked page gets deleted and the information is lost. It's discussed more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers 
For this, you may just want to copy paste the naming rule that you're referring to into your answer.

Comment: You need to rename the src folder in your project folder and also change the reference to the folder in all instances of your index.html. This includes the platforms/android/blackberry10/www/ and yourprojectfolder/www/index.html.  You should also check your reference to javasscript files in your index html and confirm that there is no missing file.